# I have to restart my router every hour or so for wireless to work

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, reboot

So this has started to become a norm in the past week. I have several devices connected to my router and most of them do so wirelessly, but a couple uses the ethernet port. About every hour my wireless devices will no longer be able to connect to the internet while the devices connected through the ethernet ports are still able to access internet. The signal from my router is still being broadcast and all the devices say that they have internet access, but it doesn't. I've tried to ping google.com, and that resulted in not being able to find host. Pinging the IP works but the request would time out. I then tried to ping my router's IP address and the request was also timed out. The only way I have been able to get back online wirelessly is by restarting the router.

I have a Linksys WRT54G with the latest firmware, v8.00.8. DHCP is enabled. wireless channel is currently on channel 11, although I tried switching to a couple with no success. These are my other settings:

[image: Image of router settings]

Note that I changed a few things from it's defaults because some sources from google search suggested, but no luck there either.

I think this is solely a router problem and I wonder if anyone knows what is going on/ knows how to fix it.

Comment: Sign onto the router and check the devices logged in, to make sure that a neighbor isn't "borrowing" your router.

Answer (score 2):

It has been several hours since i have installed dd-wrt firmware. I have not needed to restart my router since then. I still do not know what happened to cause the problem but it seems like the solution is to use dd-wrt firmware or i also heard tomato was good.

Answer (score 1):

Routers wireless hardware tend to get damaged with the pass of time. Those interruptions could be a sign that it will die soon. If you have another router lying around you can try switching them for a period of time to see if it keeps happening.

Answer (score 1):

A power issue can give these kinds of issues.  Are the router and modem connected to a UPS?  I have seen many cases where a minor dip in power (brownout) causes unusual issues with the router and/or modem as well as other hardware.

Not sure whre you are but here in Canada we are in the midst of a heat wave and I am seeing power dips several times a day.

As a small UPS is relatively inexpensive, it is worth a try.